# Error when trying to clone a project from Git in Katalon Studio

Tags: git, gitlab, git-clone, katalon

In Katalon , I am trying to clone a project from Gitlab. I am getting the below error. I am relatively new to using Katalon. Please help. I have added the necessary SSH keys to Git and Katalon.

Steps followed:

In Katalon Studio, click on Clone Project
Paste the Repository URL which was copied from GitLab using Clone with SSH.
When I click on Next, getting the error as seen in screenshot attached.
Error Details:

```
An error occurred when trying to contact XXXXX@gitlab.com:.XXXX...... Possible Reasons: Incorrect URL No network connection (eg wrong proxy settings)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvWLT.png)

Comment: Can you ping that host (gitlab.com) from that box that you are trying to clone from? If you can't ping, it _might_ be ok, as long as you get an IP in the output. But also, it looks like you are using ssh. Can you test connecting to it with ssh? If _not_, then you might have to use https instead of ssh (possibly through a proxy).

Answer (score 0):

> click on Clone Project Paste the Repository URL which was copied from Github
>
> ```
> XXXXX@gitlab.com:.XXXX
> ```

First, this looks like a gitlab.com URL, not a GitHub one.

Second, in both cases, the `XXXX@` *must* be `git@`

```
git@github.com:me/myRepo
git@gitlab.com:me/myRepo
```

The remote SSH user is *always* `git`. Your private/public key will allow GitHub or GitLab to authenticate you.

Comment: Yes, its gitlab.. sorry for the confusion... I am able to clone the project using Gitbash successfully to my local... but using Katalon I am facing issue.. the URL starts with git@ .

Comment: @Swarna Is Katalon running on the same computer as the one where you execute git bash? And using the same user account? not "root"? (On which OS are you, by the way?)

Comment: Yes, same system...same user account, this is on Windows

Comment: @Swarna Make sure your Katalon process is running as your regular account, inheriting the same environment variables as your regular CMD. If it is running as "Administrator" or "System Account", that would not work, as it would not access your SSH keys in your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` folder. Also: define a user environment variable named `HOME` set to `%USERPROFILE%`

Answer (score 0):

If your using katalon studio Trial version then you cannot add private repository via katalon's Studio Git Plugin. only Public Repo's can be added.

alternative is using Git SCM/Git Bash via command prompt.

But if you have enterprise licensed KS then it will work for public/private repo's.